# Ionic 2 Upload File to Server

Tags: angular, file-upload, ionic2

this is my upload file function:

```
uploadresume()
    {
        this.fileChooser.open()
        .then(uri => 
        {
            console.log(uri)
            const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();


            let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
                fileKey: 'file',
                fileName: 'name.pdf',
                params: {resume:uri},
                chunkedMode : false,
                headers: { Authorization:localStorage.getItem('token') }

            }
            console.log (localStorage.getItem('token'))

            fileTransfer.upload(uri, "http://website.com/upload", options1)
            .then((data) => {
                // success
                alert("success"+JSON.stringify(data));
            }, (err) => {
                // error
                alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
            });

        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
```

now my API endPoint takes in the parameter Resume with the file attached to it. But I keep getting 500 error. I am sure it's something to do with the way I am sending the file to the endpoint. Can someone please assist me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a mimeType parameter in your file upload options.

Comment: according to the documentation its optional. But I tried adding it, though it made no difference.

Comment: what mimeType did you add?

Comment: I added mimeType:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' to accept docx file that I am uploading

Comment: Try adding Content-Type as 'application/json' in the headers parameter